# Moth with silver marking on wings

Tags: species-identification, entomology, lepidoptera

This is a moth that we found on a curtain inside the house a couple of days ago. Unfortunately, these pictures did not come out as well as I thought before I realized it outside. But I was struck my the silver-white eyeglass-shaped spots on the wings. It also had an interestingly shaped head, but that didn't come out well. The closest I have come to identifying it is that it looks similar to a Dot Moth, but those don't seem to be native to Southern California (Los Angeles).

It was about an inch long, maybe less. It vibrated its wings after I disturbed it.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Whatever its identity, it is so wonderful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the overall apparence and the distinctive metallic patches on the wings it looks like a moth from the subfamily [Plusiinae](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plusiinae) (Looper moths). I'm not familiar with North American moths, but after a quick check at species found there [*Megalographa biloba*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Megalographa_biloba) (Bilobed looper moth) seems likely, and this species is also found in California.

[image]
(picture from wikipedia)

Also see the pictures at [Bugguide.net](http://bugguide.net/node/view/107124).

Comment: Excellent! I agree with your determination - I think you have it right. The front legs are similar, as are the markings (I hadn't even noticed the smaller silvery one). And the Wikipedia page shows the distinctive shape of the head that I wasn't able to capture in the photo.I would have had a lot of trouble determining that species on my own. Much appreciated!